# How to make unaccessible /root/ directory for other admin users?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, administrator

By using `sudo` command, other admin users can get access to the `/root/` directory, using their credentials. How to make it impossible ?

Comment: There are not multiple levels of admin; only one. If those admins are not trustworthy, then they should not be admins. This is essentially a can-superman-defeat-another-superman question.

Comment: Be aware the root `/` directory and `/root` (or `/root/`) are different directories; with `/` being the root directory, but `/root` referring to the *root* **user's** *configuration* directory.

Comment: @user535733 okay, got it, thanks. I thought that are 3 types of users: 1. `root` who can  do literally anything; 2. `admin` users that are managed by `root`; 3. Just users without any admin permissions.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I exactly mean `/root/` directory. But what is the difference between `/root` and `/root/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not possible.

You only can make access to `/root` impossible by removing the "sudo" permissions of the other users.

By definition, `root` can do *everything*. That includes accessing `/root`. So you better trust the people you give `sudo` priviledges because, unchangeable and by definition, you allow them access everywhere. If you do not want some users to gain access to `/root`, do not give them `sudo`privileges.

You do not state why you would ever want to deny access to `/root` to other users with `sudo` privileges. Very likely, there will be better approaches to achieve what you really are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just curious about that, currently that all is only about my local machine, so I just wanted to know. Need to know about permissions a little bit more.